# TimeOfDay giving incorrect time

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer, toolstripstatuslabel, timeofday

I made a timer which refreshes every 1000 milliseconds and I put the code as:

```
Private Sub RealTimeTMR_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RealTimeTMR.Tick
    TimeLBL.Text = TimeOfDay.ToLocalTime.ToString
End Sub
```

One would suspect this to be flawless and simple but when I start the program I get the value of the label as: 01/01/0001 18:59:36

If it make any difference to formats or anything I live in Ireland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hhbhw4c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) only does the time component and has its Date component set to all 1's.

You could use something like [`DateTime.Now`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to get this information - it should return the current local date and time of the machine it's executed on.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the time, use:

```
TimeLBL.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString("g")
```

See [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) and [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) for more information about formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jim. But I need the date also. Badly titled question, sorry.